# Right align element while a horisontal scrollbar is present

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I have a page where I want an element to align right at the same time I have elements which may be wide and cause a horisontal scrollbar. For instance:

```
<body>
<div style="float:right">Stay right</div>
<div style="white-space:nowrap; clear:both; font-size:2em">
    Wide child element which determines the width of the page.
</div>
</body>
```

This works fine if the wide element fits within the browser window. But if the browser window is too small so that a horisontal scrollbar appears the "stay right" element will align with the window and not the page:

[image: wrong right alignment]

If I move the scrollbar the "stay right" element moves and doesn't really align to anything.

If a add a table around the whole page it does what I wan't:

```
<body>
<table width="100%"><tr><td>
<div style="float:right">Stay right</div>
<div style="white-space:nowrap; clear:both; font-size:2em">
    Wide child element which determines the width of the page.
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

The "stay right" element will align with the right side of the wide child element regardless of browser window size.

Edit: The table based solution above will align right to ***largest of*** the width of the wide child element ***or*** the window width. Effectively this gives the page a "minimum width" which is determined by the contents of the page (ie. the wide child element). This is what I want - which isn't clear from the original text, sorry.

I am wondering if there is a better way than wrapping the entire page in a table.

Answer (score 3):

That is a very interesting problem.  It actually happens because the computed width on div matches the window size (and body size) instead of the width of the text.  The floating text looks to it's container for a width/height when rendering (and because that computed value is actually size of the window, the float stops at the edge of the window).

This does not really occur often because most sites use something like grid960/foundation/etc and a min/max width are provided (you probably figured out that setting a width will fix your problem).

I don't know of a really good solution for dynamically sized text (with only css)... The only thing I can think of without using a table would be to use a `clearfix`.  It is really used/created for element with floating children (in order to give them a correct width/height.. floating elements do not normally effect the containers dimensions) but it also will work in this case.

```
<body>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div style="float:right">Stay right</div>
        <div style="white-space:nowrap; clear:both; font-size:2em">
            Wide child element which determines the width of the page.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**: I lied, I came up with a second (better) way but it does require a more modern browser.  It is to use a wrapper with a `display: inline-block` OR `display: table`.  It really is just a sub-set of the `clearfix` but will work if you can get away with being IE8+ based.

```
<body>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <div style="float:right">Stay right</div>
        <div style="white-space:nowrap; clear:both; font-size:2em">
            Wide child element which determines the width of the page.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your solutions are perfect - they both does what I asked for - but not what I wanted... I need the "stay right" element to align to the largest of the wide child or the window width. This was not what the original text in the question said. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

NEVER wrap an entire page in a table. It messes up your HTML since about the year 2000.

---

I think you want a `fixed` position for your `div`, it lines up the element with the window instead of the page:

```
.myDivThatFloatsRight {
   position: fixed;
   top: 10px;
   right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this solution does not fix the problem. The myDivThatFloatsRight will not respect the width of the wide child element.